# Where can I ask Windows security related questions that are not product specific

Tags: windows-vista, security, firewall, anti-virus

Following up from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/730142/which-combinations-of-free-firewalls-and-virus-scanners-work-for-windows-vista?noredirect=1) I'd like to know if there are any Windows Security forums that are *not* product specific.

I want to use such a forum to ask about combinations of Free Firewalls and Virus Scanners are known to work well , but not limit my self to any particular products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any security product you use is only as good as its weakest link, which in most cases is almost always the human factor.

You might want to consider reading [this amusing blog post](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/12/weakest_link_se.html) by Bruce Schneier, a well known American cryptographer that outlines how even the most elaborate of security measures can be defeated by human error. The best way to prevent security mishaps from happening to you is to keep [educating yourself](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/) about the latest and greatest threats in the computer security world.

That said, [Bleeping Computer Forum](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/f/79/security/) sounds like something you might want to look into.

Comment: Perfect. That sounds like what I need